# Condition on sending request parameter with time function

Tags: jmeter

I want to send a parameter `foo` with value `${__time()}` in the request only if a certain env variable `${__P(check,true)}` equals to true, if not I want to send it with empty value

How can I do the if else in jmeter ? or what is the easiest way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible only with the help of [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

Something like:

```
if (props.get('check') == 'true') {
    def arguments = sampler.getArguments()
    if (arguments.findAll { argument -> argument.getName() == 'foo' }.size() == 0) {
        arguments.addArgument(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument("foo", System.currentTimeMillis() as String))
    }
}

sampler.setArguments(arguments)
```

where:

- `props` stand for an instance of [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) which keep all the JMeter Properties
- and the `sampler` is for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html)

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on these and other JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements.